# QEC code with transversal Hadamard on one logical qubit

Tags: error-correction

Is there a known QEC code that encodes more than one logical qubit, and which has a transversal logical Hadamard gate on only one of the logical qubits?

Comment: Presumably one could invent a [[12,2,3]] code comprising the Steane code on the first 7 qubits (transversal H) and the perfect 5-qubit code on the last 5 (no transversal H). Bit of a cheat, of course!

Comment: @DaftWullie Simple does it. I guess an interesting question would be, what is the smallest $[[n,2,d]]$ code for $d \ge 3$ which has the property OP asks for.